# Batch parameters with spaces for loop recursive move

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to put a batch together to move all `zip` files back one directory from the current directory in a recursive move where I specify the search directory from the parent.

In example, the current directory is `download` and the sub to recursive search is a command line parameter.

I then want to move the `*.zip` back one directory from `download`. I don't want to search in any other directory other than the one I specify.

```
>movezipdir junk 2009
```

This outputs `junk 2009`. Then junk was unexpected at this time.

Here's what I have but the for loop doesn't like the variable with spaces...

```
@echo off
IF %1.==. GOTO No1
set DirName=%*
echo %DirName%
For /d %DirName% in ( *.* ) do (
    For /d %%e in (""%DirName%"\*") do (
rem     move /Y "%%e\*.zip" "%CD%\.."
echo    %DirName%
rem     rd /S /Q "%%e"
    )
rem rd /S /Q %DirName%
        )   
GOTO End1
:No1
  ECHO No Directory Specified
GOTO End1
:End1
```

It would be great if someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks. Ken

Comment: `for /d %DirName%` is incorrect.  The syntax should be `for /d %%I` where *I* is any single letter.  Or, since you mentioned you want a recursive search, you might've meant `for /r "%DirName%" %%I in...`.  See `help for` in a cmd console for more info.  You also need to retrieve `"%%~e"` with the tilde to strip *im*plicit surrounding quotation marks (if any) while adding your own *ex*plicitly.

Comment: The task isn't 100% clear as there are no examples.   You mention `recursive` but only talk about one folder, and end by saying you only want to search one directory.  If you edit your question to improve the description then it will also be more useful for future readers with a similar problem.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, When I say recursive, I meant there may or may not be sub folders to search under the specified directory.

Comment: In an example, specified directory junk 2009 could have directories junk1 and junk2 with zip files in each with the objective to move the zips up one directory from the parent directory of download.

Comment: Rojo, thank you very much! I've gotten it to work with your suggestions. Appreciated! Here is the code I used...@echo off
IF %1.==. GOTO No1
set DirName=%*

For /r "%DirName%" %%I in ("%DirName%") do (
 For /r "%DirName%" %%e in (*) do (
 move /Y "%%e" "%CD%\.."
   )
  )
rd /S /Q "%DirName%"
 
GOTO End1
:No1
  ECHO No Directory Specified
GOTO End1
:End1

Answer (score 0):

```vb
@echo off

rem :: check if the args is not nul
if [%1] == [] (
    goto error
    ) else (
    for /f "usebackq tokens=1*" %%i in ('echo %*') do (
        set "dirname=%%~i"
    )
)

rem check if the specified args correspond to a directory
if exist "%dirname%\nul" echo %dirname% it's a directory || goto error

set /a c=1
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s /a-d "%dirname%\*.txt"') do (

    rem usage: move [{/y | /-y}] [Source] [Target]
    rem https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772528.aspx
    rem http://ss64.com/nt/move.html
    rem %cd% here are redundant because when target are omitted,
    rem  the target are always the current directory
    echo move /-y "%%a" "%cd%"

    rem break loop after 5 iterations.
    rem You can remove it if the test are Okay
    if [!c!] equ [5] goto break_loop
    set /a c+=1

)
:break_loop
rem usage: RD [/S] [/Q] [drive:]path
echo rd /s /q %dirname%
exit /b 0

:error
echo     Error: No directory specified or invalid arguments
echo     Usage: %~0 ^<full path of the directorys^>
echo   Example: %~0 c:\user\janne\MyDocuments
exit /b 0
```